# ¿Crear tabla dinámica a partir de un objeto Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Buen día

Estoy creando una tabla dinámica con los datos de que obtengo a partir de una consulta, los datos me llegan en un objeto como este:

```
    var data = [
                {id:1, land:FINCA1,  product: "ROSA",    week:25, quantity: 2000},
                {id:1, land:FINCA2,  product: "ROSA",    week:25, quantity: 1900},
                {id:1, land:FINCA3,  product: "ROSA",    week:25, quantity: 350},
                {id:1, land:FINCA3,  product: "TULIPAN", week:25, quantity: 410},
                {id:1, land:FINCA1,  product: "ROSA",    week:26, quantity: 1254},
                {id:1, land:FINCA2,  product: "ROSA",    week:26, quantity: 123},
                {id:1, land:FINCA3,  product: "ROSA",    week:26, quantity: 200}
               ]
```

Los datos pueden variar dependiendo de la consulta, ya que es un formulario con `checkboxes`, si el usuario selecciona mas datos el objeto puede ser mas grande, Ejemplo:

```
var data = [ {"id":1, "land":"FINCA1", "product": "ROSA","variety": "R01", "week":25, "quantity": 2000},
             {"id":1, "land":"FINCA2", "product": "ROSA", "variety": "R01", "week":25, "quantity": 1900},
             {"id":1, "land":"FINCA3", "product": "ROSA", "variety": "R01", "week":25, "quantity": 350},
             {"id":1, "land":"FINCA3", "product": "ROSA1", "variety": "V01", "week":25, "quantity": 410},
             {"id":1, "land":"FINCA1", "product": "ROSA", "variety": "A01", "week":26, "quantity": 1254},
             {"id":1, "land":"FINCA2", "product": "ROSA", "variety": "A01", "week":26, "quantity": 123},
             {"id":1, "land":"FINCA3", "product": "ROSA", "variety": "A01", "week":26, "quantity": 200}
           ];
```

En este último caso el usuario seleccionar "variety" y en el objeto me llega el dato adicional.

Recorrí el objeto con un `for` y armé la tabla de la siguiente manera (NOTA: Aquí no es dinámica la tabla, sólo es como lo hice):

```
tableHead = '<tr>'+
             '<td>Land</td>'+
             '<td>Product</td>'+
             '<td>Week</td>'+
             '<td>Quantity</td>'+
            '</tr>;

for(var i in data){

table += '<tr>'+
           '<td>'+data[i]['land']+'</td>'+
           '<td>'+data[i]['product']+'</td>'+
           '<td>'+data[i]['week']+'</td>'+
           '<td>'+data[i]['quantity']+'</td>'+
         '</tr>;
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien la tabla queda así (Cómo se vería en el html):

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Land    |     Product    |    Week   |    Quantity    |
-------------------------------------------------------
FINCA1  |     ROSA       |     25    |     2000       |
-------------------------------------------------------
FINCA2  |     ROSA       |     25    |     1900       |
-------------------------------------------------------
FINCA3  |     ROSA       |     25    |     350        |
-------------------------------------------------------
FINCA3  |     ROSA1      |     25    |     410        |
-------------------------------------------------------
FINCA1  |     ROSA       |     26    |     1254       |
-------------------------------------------------------
FINCA2  |     ROSA       |     26    |     123        |
-------------------------------------------------------
FINCA3  |     ROSA       |     26    |     200        |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

El dilema es que quiero que los valores de "Week" queden en las columnas de las tabla y los valores de  "Quantity" queden de acuerdo a los valores de "Week" es decir que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Land     |     Product   |    25   |    26   | Total |
-----------------------------------------------------
FINCA1   |     ROSA      |   2000  |   1254  |  3254 |
-----------------------------------------------------
FINCA2   |     ROSA      |   1900  |   123   |  2023 |
-----------------------------------------------------
FINCA3   |     ROSA      |   350   |   200   |  550  |
-----------------------------------------------------
FINCA3   |     ROSA1     |   410   |    0    |  410  |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

He intentando muchas maneras de crear la tabla de esta manera, la consulta esta bien, lo que no he podido es organizarlo, he intentado los siguiente:

```
//Obtengo los keys del objeto para crear el Thead de la tabla y los guardo en una variable

var row = Object.keys(data[0]);

//Recorro la variable para crear el Thead
tableHead = '<tr>';

for(var a in row){
  tableHead += '<th>'+row[a]+'</th>';
}

tableHead += '<th>Total</th>' +
             '</tr>';

//Para el tbody con los datos he intentado lo siguiente pero no me funciona, recorro la variable row con los campos del thead y los comparo con el objeto data para que traiga los datos correspondientes

var datos = [];
for(var d=0; d < data.length; d++){
 for(var e = 0; e < rowH.length; e++){
   var controlchange += data[d][rowH[e]];
   datos.push(data[d][rowH[e]]);
 }
}

tableBody = '<tr>';
for(var g in datos){
 table += '<td>'+datos[g]+'</td>'+
          '</tr>;    
}
```

Espero mi pregunta sea entendida, y que me puedan brindar alguna asesoría, he investigado y no he podido solucionarlo, Muchas gracias!

Comment: Obtienes los datos a través de una consulta, ¿tienes control sobre esa consulta? Este problema parece que sería más sencillo de solucionar si cambiases la consulta para que los datos se devolvieran en un orden/estructura diferente a la que obtienes ahora mismo

Comment: Si tengo control, el problema es que la consulta es grande, así que me pareció optar mejor ubicar los datos en Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me he tomado un tiempo para realizar el ejemplo, puedes coger muchas ideas de aquí:

```js
var data = [
  {id:1, land: 'FINCA1',  product: "ROSA", variety: "R01", week:25,  quantity: 2000}, {id:1, land: 'FINCA2', product: "ROSA", variety: "R01", week:25, quantity: 1900}, {id:1, land: 'FINCA3',  product: "ROSA",    variety: "R01", week:25, quantity: 350},{id:1, land: 'FINCA3',  product: "ROSA1",   variety: "V01", week:25, quantity: 410},{id:1, land: 'FINCA1',  product: "ROSA",    variety: "A01", week:26, quantity: 1254},{id:1, land: 'FINCA2' ,  product: "ROSA",    variety: "A01", week:26, quantity: 123},{id:1, land: 'FINCA3' ,  product: "ROSA",    variety: "A01", week:26, quantity: 200}
];

//Obtengo los keys del objeto para crear el Thead de la tabla y los guardo en una variable

var tabla = document.createElement('table');
var tableHead = document.createElement('tr');

Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(prop=>{
  if(prop != 'week' && prop != 'quantity')
  tableHead.innerHTML += '<th>'+prop+'</th>';
});

var semanas = data.reduce( (semanas_, elemento)=>{
  if(semanas_.indexOf(elemento.week) == -1)
    semanas_.push(elemento.week)
  return semanas_;
}, []);

semanas.forEach( semana=>{
  tableHead.innerHTML += '<th>'+semana+'</th>';
});

tableHead.innerHTML += '<th>Total</th>';
tabla.appendChild(tableHead);

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

tabla.appendChild(tbody);

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(tabla);

var arrayOrganizado = data.reduce((arr, item)=>{
  item.week = {
    numero : item.week,
    cantidad : item.quantity
  }
  var ele = arr.find(it=>it.land === item.land && it.product === item.product);
  if(ele){
    ele.week.push(item.week);
    ele.total = ele.week.reduce((a, b)=> a + b.cantidad, 0);
  } else {
    item.week = [item.week];
    item.total = item.quantity;
    arr.push(item);
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

arrayOrganizado.forEach(fila=>{
  var f = Object.keys(fila).reduce( (a, b)=>{
    //console.log(b);
    if(b != 'week' && b != 'quantity' && b != 'total')
      return a +  '<td>' + fila[b] + '</td>';
    return a;
  }, '');
  tbody.innerHTML += f + semanas.reduce( (a, _, i)=>a + '<td>' + (fila.week[i] ? fila.week[i].cantidad : 0) + '</td>', '') + '<td>' + fila.total + '</td>';   
});
```

Si lo probamos con el primer array de datos:

```js
var data = [{id:1, land: 'FINCA1',  product: "ROSA", week:25,  quantity: 2000}, {id:1, land: 'FINCA2', product: "ROSA", week:25, quantity: 1900}, {id:1, land: 'FINCA3',  product: "ROSA", week:25, quantity: 350},{id:1, land: 'FINCA3',  product: "ROSA1", week:25, quantity: 410},{id:1, land: 'FINCA1',  product: "ROSA", week:26, quantity: 1254},{id:1, land: 'FINCA2' ,  product: "ROSA", week:26, quantity: 123},{id:1, land: 'FINCA3' ,  product: "ROSA", week:26, quantity: 200}
];


//Obtengo los keys del objeto para crear el Thead de la tabla y los guardo en una variable

var tabla = document.createElement('table');
var tableHead = document.createElement('tr');

Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(prop=>{
  if(prop != 'week' && prop != 'quantity')
  tableHead.innerHTML += '<th>'+prop+'</th>';
});

var semanas = data.reduce( (semanas_, elemento)=>{
  if(semanas_.indexOf(elemento.week) == -1)
    semanas_.push(elemento.week)
  return semanas_;
}, []);

semanas.forEach( semana=>{
  tableHead.innerHTML += '<th>'+semana+'</th>';
});

tableHead.innerHTML += '<th>Total</th>';
tabla.appendChild(tableHead);

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

tabla.appendChild(tbody);

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(tabla);

var arrayOrganizado = data.reduce((arr, item)=>{
  item.week = {
    numero : item.week,
    cantidad : item.quantity
  }
  var ele = arr.find(it=>it.land === item.land && it.product === item.product);
  if(ele){
    ele.week.push(item.week);
    ele.total = ele.week.reduce((a, b)=> a + b.cantidad, 0);
  } else {
    item.week = [item.week];
    item.total = item.quantity;
    arr.push(item);
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

arrayOrganizado.forEach(fila=>{
  var f = Object.keys(fila).reduce( (a, b)=>{
    //console.log(b);
    if(b != 'week' && b != 'quantity' && b != 'total')
      return a +  '<td>' + fila[b] + '</td>';
    return a;
  }, '');
  tbody.innerHTML += f + semanas.reduce( (a, _, i)=>a + '<td>' + (fila.week[i] ? fila.week[i].cantidad : 0) + '</td>', '') + '<td>' + fila.total + '</td>';   
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo que le dedicaste, voy a revisarlo Saludos!

Comment: De acuerdo hzme saber cuándo lo revises! :)

Comment: Si funcionó gracias! , pero algo que me falto en la pregunta es que el objeto puede tener más datos de acuerdo a las opciones que se escojan, ya que al seleccionarlo me muestra siempre los cuatro elementos que tiene el objeto, me tocaría mirar como puedo hacer eso, pero en realidad me ayudo bastante

Comment: Tienes razón! Editaré la respuesta cuando pueda pero básicamente en la última parte del código arrayOrganizado.forEach... tendrías que volver a recorrer las propiedades de todas las claves de los objetos y formar el HTML excluyendo las claves week y quantity.

Comment: Voy a intentar a hacerlo, pero si necesitaré asesoría, Muchas gracias!

Comment: Ahí lo tienes! Como te digo, alomejor se podrían omitir ciertos pasos y hacerlo más funcional pero ahí tienes la idea! El código ten en cuenta que funcionará siempre y cuando existan en los datos las propiedades "week" y "quantity".

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona muy bien, me salvaste de mucho, Saludos!